# How to make an animation stop at a specific position along a path?

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, cakeyframeanimation

I'm trying to make an animation where an image moves along a circle path and stops.  I can get the image to follow the path but am having problems making it stop at specific points. I tried doing keyframe values but since the path is circular, when I enter a keyframe value it doesn't move along the path instead either moves along the x or y axis (postion.x, position.y, position.xy). In the viewDidAppear I'm trying to make the image move in and stop at the UIImageView on the top right corner as seen in the storyboard below:
[image: ImageView]

Once a button is pressed the image will continue to move along the circle path off screen. Currently here is the code :

```
  func moveMatchIn() {

    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x:view.frame.width, y:view.frame.height/2), radius: CGFloat(200), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(CGFloat.pi * 2), clockwise: false).cgPath

    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.speed = 0.5
    animation.path = circlePath

    theyMatchImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    theyMatchImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    theyMatchImageView.image = matchImage
    theyMatchImageView.setRounded()

    view.addSubview(theyMatchImageView)
    theyMatchImageView.layer.add(animation, forKey: "position")

    // circleLayer is only used to locate the circle animation path
    let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    circleLayer.path = circlePath
    circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    view.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
  }
```

Comment: Do some math to figure out where your thing should be on the circle based on the time (yay trig!). Then you can remove the animation and update the position of the view.